# Powershell redirect all output streams to file and errors to console

Tags: powershell, io-redirection

I would like to redirect all output to a file (`*> file`) and only errors to the console (`2>`) but can't find a way to do that.

Tried this which gives an error:

```bsh
Write-Error "error" *> all.log 2>

+ Write-Error "error" *> all.log 2>
+                                 ~
Missing file specification after redirection operator.
```

I tried adding a `file` as the error message suggests just to see if the redirection would work in this case but it doesn't:

```bsh
Write-Error "error" *> all.log 2> errors.log
# all.log is empty but should contain the error also
# errors.log contains error
```

I also tried combining streams with no luck:

```bsh
Write-Error "error" 2>&1 all.log 2> errors.log

+ Write-Error "error" 2>&1 all.log 2> errors.log
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The error stream for this command is already redirected.
```

Tried some things with `tee` also but couldn't get that to work either. It seems like the problem is that you can't redirect a stream more than once or output it to two places? Is there a way to get around this or solve it in some neat way?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple way to get this because you can't redirect to two different places.

If your logic isn't too complex, something like this should work:

```
function Redirect($output)
{
    # If the last operation was a success $? will be true
    if($?)
    {
        $output | Out-File -FilePath "all.log" -Append
    }
    else
    {
        # $Error[0] is the message of the last error which was already displayed on the screen
        $Error[0] | Out-File -FilePath "all.log" -Append
    }
}


Redirect (Get-ChildItem "exists")
Redirect (Get-ChildItem "nonexistent")
```

From the command line, the output looks like this:

```
PS C:\temp> C:\temp\test.ps1
Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path 'C:\temp\nonexistent' because it does not exist.
At C:\temp\test.ps1:15 char:11
+ Redirect (Get-ChildItem "nonexistent")
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\temp\nonexistent:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotF 
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Contents of all.log:

```
    Directory: C:\temp\exists


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                               
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                               
-a----        2020-04-22   8:44 AM              0 here.txt                                           


Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\temp\nonexistent' because it does not exist.
At C:\temp\test.ps1:15 char:11
+ Redirect (Get-ChildItem "nonexistent")
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\temp\nonexistent:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotF 
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```